# captionof, hyperref and autoref: wrong tag?

Tags: hyperref, captions

This is probably an abuse of one (or more) of `captionof`, `hyperref` and `\autoref` command.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Some text and some more text.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        This will be\par
        A figure

        \caption{A figure!\label{fig}}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        This will be\par
        A table

        \captionof{table}{A table!\label{tab}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

This is a figure: \autoref{fig} and this a table: \autoref{tab}.

\end{document}
```

The `\autoref` got confused by the surrounding `figure` (I think), and it gives:

[image]

Is there a workaround? I can do `... Table~\ref{tab}` alright, but now the hyperlink is just on the number...

Comment: You could try `\captionsetup{type=table}\caption{A table!\label{tab}}` (can't test now).

Comment: @campa yes, it seems to work ok! Thanks. Please make an answer when you have time...

Comment: This looks like a bug in \captionof, it doesn't create a destination, so the link is wrong too (not obvious here as they are side-by-side).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for the comments. I'll open an issue with the maintainer of `captions`.

Comment: Done, https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/119

Comment: Uhm, it was a lucky guess. I checked the doc and that "solution" is proposed for an entirely different problem. I have no idea why it's working here and I don't feel comfortable in writing an answer.

Comment: @campa ok, let's wait and see if the author can comment. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @campa the author commented in https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/119#note_510941378

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the author said "not my fault ;-)" and offered a reasonable workaround https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/119#note_510941378